# manage search schedule in SharePoint

Tags: search, 2016

my farm about 700 gb , I want to configure search crawl schedule to run in daily basis!

- which crawl type should I use, continuous or incremental and why?
- which crawl setting should I set?

additionally,  i set daily , and number of days is 1!

I am confused which value should I add at

- every
- for

thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have a very good reason not to, you should enable Continuous Crawl. Do not schedule any full crawls. Full crawls cause the index to be out of date until completion of the crawl, which is usually undesirable.

Comment: thanks for the quick response, why should I use continuous not incremental? what are the setting for every and for value

Comment: CC is intelligent overlapping incrementals. It gives you much higher search freshness and you don't have to be concerned with properly scheduling incrementals.

Comment: means I would set to continuous without schedule is it right?

Comment: Yep, just select the CC radio box on your content source and that's it.

Comment: thank you, is there any performance impact with the cc

Comment: enable continuous set automatically schedule runs every 4 hours and can't select none! is it normal

Comment: Yes, that is normal. And there is always an impact to crawling. You should be using a hosts file and point your crawlers at the local servers or a box dedicated to crawling rather than relying on DNS.